# database text field databound to a checkbox

Tags: c#, data-binding, checkbox

I'd like the field to save as a 1 or 0 instead of 'True' or 'False' in the database and i cannot figure out how to do it without manually setting every property when the record is saved. I have to use this a lot in this project and a bit field is not an option. I would like to solve this issue by extending the CheckBox control if possible but i don't know how to change the binding fields value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are we talking web, windows, wpf, etc program?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clearer. I'm using nhibernate objects with win forms. A string property of the object is bound to a checkbox and it get's set to 'True' or 'False' from the checkbox. I'd rather the string's value get set to 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use int,varchar or any other type in the database.
In your select statement use the when clause

```
Select field1, field2, case when field3=value then True else False end as field3
From Table
```

Comment: I guess i could do that. Thanks